# Select cases from long table by key variable grouping

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like below:

```
caseid | ncode | code | test
   1       1      ABC    TRUE
   1       2      DEF    TRUE
   2       1      ABC    TRUE 
   3       1      DEF    TRUE
   3       2      HIJ    FALSE
```

Where `caseid` represents an individual case. This table creates the relationship that each individual case can have multiple codes associated with it (`ncode` and `code`). `test` is just a variable that tracks a boolean value of interest.

I have specific requirements for my query:

1. I need all cases where `code = ABC` and `ncode = 1` and `test = TRUE`. **This criteria has the highest priority**.
2. Of those cases from  #1, I need to create an additional column called `hasdef` that is a boolean that indicates if that specific `caseid` has *any other* rows where `code = DEF` and `test = TRUE`. It should be `TRUE` if so, otherwise `FALSE`.

So from the above table, what should return is:

```
caseid | ncode | code | test | hasdef
   1       1      ABC    TRUE   TRUE
   2       1      ABC    TRUE   FALSE
```

`caseid = 1` returns because `code = ABC`, `ncode = 1`, and `test = TRUE`. `hasdef = TRUE` because in the second row, `caseid = 1`, `code = DEF` and `test = TRUE`.

`caseid = 2` returns because `code = ABC`, `ncode = 1`, and `test = TRUE`. `hasdef = FALSE` because there is no other row with `caseid = 2` where `code = DEF`.

`caseid = 3` does not return. Even though there is a row where `code = DEF` and `test = TRUE`, the first criteria (`code = ABC` and `ncode = 1`) is not first satisfied.

This is what I have so far, but I am not confident it is working as desired:

```
select tab1.*, tab2.code is not null as hasdef from
(select * from mytable
where code = 'ABC' and ncode = 1) as tab1

left join (
select caseid, any_value(code) code,  any_value(test) test
from mytable
group by caseid
having code = 'DEF' and test is true
) as tab2
using(caseid)

order by caseid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select * from (
  select *, 
    0 < countif(code = 'DEF' and test is true) over(partition by caseid) as hasdef
  from `project.dataset.table` 
)
where code = 'ABC' and ncode = 1 and test is true
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Note: you can replace `test is true` with just `test` as in below

```
select * from (
  select *, 
    0 < countif(code = 'DEF' and test) over(partition by caseid) as hasdef
  from `project.dataset.table` 
)
where code = 'ABC' and ncode = 1 and test
```